# Prove every isometry of the plane is expressible as product of reflections, translations, rotations

Tags: group-theory

> Prove every isometry of the plane is expressible as product of reflections, translations, rotations

I know that the distance preserving isometries are a group but I have no idea how to use this information.

Answer (score 2):

Let $P$ be an isometry of the plane. Let $P(0)=x$. Let us denote translation by $T_x(y)=y+x$. Then define $U=T_{-x}\circ P$. Note that $U(0)=0$ and $U$ is an isometry. Now by the isometry definition, $|U(y)|=d(U(y), U(0))=d(y, 0)=|y|$. We see that since an isometry preserves triangles, that $U(x+y)=U(x)+U(y)$, and clearly $aU(x)=U(ax)$. Thus our map $U$ is a linear transformation. Now consider the image of $(1, 0)$. Since it lies on the unit circle (points of norm $1$), its image does to, and thus $U(1, 0)=(\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta))$. Likewise $U(0, 1)=(\cos(\phi), \sin(\phi))$. Now we note that since isometries preserve angles, $|\theta-\phi|=\pi/2$. Now either we have that $\phi=\theta+\pi/2$, and we can see that $U$ is rotation by $\theta$, or $\phi=\theta-\pi/2$ and we can see that it is the product of a reflection and then rotation by $\theta$. Now multiplying $U$ by $T_{x}$ to get $P$, we have the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** An isometry of the plane is uniquely determined by the image of three non-collinear points.

Answer (score 0):

The parallelogram identity gives $2(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2) = \|x+y\|^2+\|x-y\|^2$.

The polarization identity gives $\langle x , y \rangle = {1 \over 4} (\|x+y\||^2-\|x-y\|^2) = {1 \over 2} (\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2-\|x-y\|^2)$.

Let $\phi$ be an isometry, and let $g(x) = \phi(x)-\phi(0)$ so that $g(0) = 0$. Then the identity gives us
$\langle g(x) , g(y) \rangle = \langle x , y \rangle$.

It follows from this that $g(e_1),g(e_2)$ form an orthonormal basis for the plane.

Then we have $\langle g(\lambda x) , g(y) \rangle = \langle \lambda x , y \rangle = \lambda \langle x , y \rangle = \lambda \langle g(x) , g(y) \rangle = \langle \lambda g( x) , g(y) \rangle$. Since this is true for all $y$ (in particular for $e_1,e_2$), we see that we must have $g(\lambda x ) = \lambda g(x)$.

The same sort of analysis shows that $g(x+y) = g(x)+g(y)$, from which we conclude that $g$ is linear. Hence we can write $g(x) = Gx$ for some matrix $G$.

Since $\langle g(x) , g(y) \rangle = \langle Gx , Gy \rangle = \langle G^TGx , y \rangle = \langle x , y \rangle$ for all $x,y$, we see that $G^T G = I$, and so $G$ is orthogonal.

We have that $G e_1, G e_2$ are orthonormal. Let $J=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, a rotation of ${\pi \over 2}$. Hence we must have 
$G e_2 = \pm J G e_1$, and so $G$ has the form $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a \end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & -a \end{bmatrix}$, with $a^2+b^2 = 1$. Hence $G$ can be expressed as a rotation possible composed with a reflection.

To finish, note that $\phi(x) = \phi(0) + G x$.